# How to handle Caching before it has been set and multiple users access the website at the same time

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, caching, memorycache

I have set up Caching for my website, which expires after an hour. 
So my problem is if the Cache does not exist and Multiple users access the website at the same time I would like to avoid all the users making the same request at the same time. As this has an impact on the CPU usage to be at 100% for a longer period of time.

I am using System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache.

MVC ASP.NET application.

I have thought of a solution but I am not sure how to best implement it, my thoughts are,

One of the many users will first come in first, and start a request and I set a flag to say fetching data and then after any more users come in they will be shown no cache has been set but before starting the request they will check the flag if the request has already been triggered. If it has the application should wait until a response has come back (is this possible?), and then use the response from the cache. 
This way One request is sent and it will be quicker response from the service and it will be a quicker response and CPU usage will still be quite low.

*Please do suggest an alternative to this, my idea could be wrong*

Can someone please advise?

Thanks

Comment: what are you catching exactly? Data I guess? Is that flag a static flag...I supposed?

Comment: Hi @Leo I haven't implemented the flag yet. But yes it would be a static variable.